# Which hook will be trigger, when newsletter list of ps_emailsubscription will be updated after DOI

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I need some help, which hook will be triggered when newsletter-list of ps_emailsubscription will be updated after DOI confirmation.

What is the availability of hooks for ps_emailsubscription? Need to trigger a call after DOI confirmation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this hook that has been added to the module recently:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_emailsubscription/pull/84